# LPdir not implemented, what is it for?

Tags: c, openssl

I have a problem with Openssl on a non *nix/Windows/Mac platform.

The same C code (except for some tweaks to make it run on Windows, the SSL logic is the same) on Windows as on my platform works perfectly. Server and client can authenticate each other.
However on my platform the client does not authenticate the server. The server certificate is not valid even though it works when the client is run on WIndows.
I have also double checked with openssl via the command line that the CA and cert belong together. So it is a problem on my platform.

I have some warnings when I compile on my platform which could be related to this.

One is LPDIR_H. I have LPdir_nyi.h (not yet implemented). The functions in this file finds a file (LP_find_file) and finds the END of a file (LP_find_file_end). Maybe that is the problem.

When are these files used? I can't find any obvious calls to these functions so I don't know if they are even used by openssl?

Edit:
I should add that the function SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations returns correctly. Investigating if the SSL_add_dir_cert_subjects_to_stack is called by it.

Answer (score 1):

They are the implementations of `OPENSSL_DIR_read` and `OPENSSL_DIR_end`. From `crypto/o_dir.c`:

```
/* The routines really come from the Levitte Programming, so to make
   life simple, let's just use the raw files and hack the symbols to
   fit our namespace.  */
#define LP_DIR_CTX OPENSSL_DIR_CTX
#define LP_dir_context_st OPENSSL_dir_context_st
#define LP_find_file OPENSSL_DIR_read
#define LP_find_file_end OPENSSL_DIR_end

#include "o_dir.h"

#define LPDIR_H
#if defined OPENSSL_SYS_UNIX || defined DJGPP
#include "LPdir_unix.c"
#elif defined OPENSSL_SYS_VMS
#include "LPdir_vms.c"
#elif defined OPENSSL_SYS_WIN32
#include "LPdir_win32.c"
#elif defined OPENSSL_SYS_WINCE
#include "LPdir_wince.c"
#else
#include "LPdir_nyi.c"
#endif
```

Yes, they really `#define` the function names to other names before `#including` the definitions, so that the compiler never sees any symbols `LP_find_file` and `LP_find_file_end`. As far as anything after the preprocessor is concerned, they will be called `OPENSSL_DIR_read` and `OPENSSL_DIR_end`.

`OPENSSL_DIR_read` is used in `SSL_add_dir_cert_subjects_to_stack`, so it seems plausible that your problem could be related to this.

The functions are also not terribly complex and should be fairly simple to reimplement. `LP_find_file` (well, `OPENSSL_DIR_read`) opens a directory context the first time it is called (i.e., with the address of a null pointer) and returns something describing the context and the first file name in the directory, and from the second call onwards just steps to the next file name until there aren't any more, whereupon it returns `NULL`. `LP_find_file_end`/`OPENSSL_DIR_end` just closes the context. I don't know what platform you're working on, but I'd be surprised if there were no functions in its API that could be mapped to this easily.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. The problem is I can't find a single call to SSL_add_dir_cert_subjects_to_stack or its redefinition    SSL_add_dir_cert_subjs_to_stk. SO I am not sure if it is called at all.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's an API function that you have to call yourself to initialize the stack of certificates to use for verification. If you don't use it, this may not be the unimplemented feature you're looking for, although I have to hedge in that there's too much macro magic in OpenSSL to trust `grep` to determine whether a function is used internally or not. You could, I suppose, compile OpenSSL with debug symbols yourself and place a breakpoint in `LPDIR_find_file` during debugging (or a logging statement, if a proper debugger for that platform is not available) to see if it is hit.